# labeling of values in XRD spectral peaks

Tags: label, gnuplot, spectra

Following this old post, I am curious to know how you can put the labels, manually, on the peaks.

[Gnuplot XRD graph, connecting points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52240298/gnuplot-xrd-graph-connecting-points)

to have something like this: 
[image]

**Edition 1**

I have modified both codes to adapt it to what I want, but I have an error.

My code is as following:

```
set terminal postscript enhanced color"Times-Roman" 20
set xlabel "2{/Symbol Q} (°)"
set ylabel "Intensity (a.u.)"
set xrange [10:90]
set key off
set decimalsign
set output "UHTC-XRD.eps"
set palette defined (1 "red", 2 "green", 3 "blue")
unset colorbox
array Materials[3] = ["ZrB_2", "SiC", "C"]
Gap = 150
Length = 500
plot  "XRD_UHTC_data.txt" using 2:1 with lines lc rgb "blue" title "lines", "peaksUHTC.txt" for [i=1:3] '' u (i==$3?$2:NaN):($1+Gap+Length+Gap):3 w p pt 7 palette title Materials[i]
```

For the following spectrum data (I will only indicate a few lines, + 4000):

```
147 10.01
181 10.03
169 10.05
148 10.07
162 10.09
165 10.11
167 10.13
```

and I get this figure:
[image]

First question, how can I remove the y-axis values?
About the labeling of the peaks, I have made the following file as an example

```
# PosY PeakX  Category
10697 41.77 1
6383 32.73 1
259 35.81 2
101 16.27 3
```

but I have this error in the main file:

*"gnuXRD_UHTC.txt" line 26: unexpected or unrecognized token*

and I can not see what is wrong.

Comment: it should be `..., for [i=1:3] "peaksUHTC.txt" u (i==$3?$2:NaN) ...`. Replace `''` from my code with the your peak-filename.

Comment: Nope, still gives error `plot  "XRD_UHTC_data.txt" using 2:1 with lines lc rgb "blue" title "lines", "peaksUHTC.txt" for [i=1:3] "peaksUHTC.txt" u (i==$3?$2:NaN):($1+Gap+Length+Gap):3 w p pt 7 palette title Materials[i]`

Comment: I wrote `for [i=1:3] "peaksUHTC.txt"` _not_ `"peaksUHTC.txt" for [i=1:3]` and _not_ `"peaksUHTC.txt" for [i=1:3] "peaksUHTC.txt"`

Comment: Yes now. And to be able to remove the Y axis values?

Comment: Check the manual or `help xtics`.
If you want neither tics nor numbers use `unset ytics`. If you want to keep tics but just remove the numbers use `set format y ""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion (requires gnuplot >=5.2): you need to have a datafile/datablock which contains the peak positions, peak intensities as well as the material class (e.g. as a number).
Since I don't have the XRD-data, I'm simply plotting the peaks with impulses (replace this line with your XRD-data).
Then use `with vectors` for the short line above the peaks and `with points` for the symbol.
One way is to use a palette to get the colors as function of the material class.
In order to get the coloring of the legend right, you need to skip certain curves when looping through your materials (expression: `...(i==$3?$1:NaN)...`)
Perhaps, there are other (easier?) ways to accomplish the same result.

**Code:**

```
### labeling of peaks
reset session

$PeakData <<EOD
# PosX PeakY  Category
9.56   998.8  2
11.2  1215.9  3
26.9  1315.0  1
34.6  4927.5  1
36.6  1023.1  1
42.1  1262.3  1
46.0  1609.7  4
50.5  1404.1  1
55.4  1393.8  1
55.5  1686.6  2
56.9  1545.7  3
66.4   581.4  1
67.8   722.5  3
72.0   679.6  2
72.9   571.2  3
74.9   419.5  3
76.9   582.4  4
78.3   484.9  1
EOD

Gap = 150
Length = 500
set palette defined (1 "red", 2 "green", 3 "blue", 4 "orange")
unset colorbox
array Materials[4] = ["Material 1", "Material 2", "Material 3", "Material 4"]

plot $PeakData u 1:2 with impulses lw 2 lc rgb "violet" notitle, \
     $PeakData u 1:($2+Gap):(0):(Length) with vectors nohead notitle, \
     for [i=1:4] '' u (i==$3?$1:NaN):($2+Gap+Length+Gap):3 w p pt 7 palette title Materials[i]
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: the following might also be interesting for you: a gnuplot peak-finder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56606820/7295599

Comment: Thanks a lot. Truly that it is a good post. Pity not having found it before to search 50 peaks manually. But great for the next time.

Comment: well, I just posted it 19 hours ago... ;-) Actually, it could be slightly extended to automatically list and mark for example the 50 most prominent peaks. No fiddling around with finding the proper threshold.